# import / export const from other screen. - React native

Tags: react-native

I have two screens:

1. Details - Here is an 'Add to Order' button, When user click current item should get pushed to cart without user navigating to PayMentDetails screen.
2. Payment Details screen - Should diplay cart items.

   ```
   export const [cartIT, setCartIT] = useState([]);


   function PaymentScreen({route, navigation}) {
    const { confirmPayment, loading } = useConfirmPayment();
    const {it} = route.params;

    return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
        data={cartIT}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Image style={{height: imageHeight/2, width: imageWidth}} source={{ uri: item.picture.large }}/>}
      />
    </View>);
   ```

   }

On click of button of Details screen, I have following code to add json obj to an array defined in PaymentScreen:

```
import { cartIT, setCartIT } from "./PaymentScreen";
....
return (
    <View>
        <Image style={{height: imageHeight/2, width: imageWidth}} source={{ uri: it.picture.large }}/>
        <Button title="Add to CART" style={{with: '20%'}} 
        onPress={() => {
            setCartIT(...cartIT, it);
        }}
        >Add to Order</Button>
```

On Application start I get warning/error that hooks are not called inside the function body, If I put insside function body, I cannot use 'export'

Is there no way to update/delete constant/variables of defined in other .js file (If the user dont want to navigate to next screen - PaymentScreen in this case.)

What is the alternate to achieve this.